# Can only merge Series or DataFrame objects, a <class 'NoneType'> was passed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, merge

I'm trying to get monthly information from tables that are available in pdf format. I wrote a code that works well but I have errors with some specific months. What I've done is this:

```
def provincias(codigo,pages:list):
    box = [4,2.8,19,27]
    fc = 28.28
    for i in range(0, len(box)):
      box[i] *= fc

    path = "http://www.bcra.gob.ar/Pdfs/PublicacionesEstadisticas/BoletinEstadistico/" + 'boldat' + str(codigo) +".pdf"
    tables = read_pdf(path, pages=pages, area=[box], stream=True)

    tablas1 = pd.DataFrame()
    tablas2 = pd.DataFrame()

    for page in pages:
      if page % 2 != 0:
          tablas1 = pd.concat(tables)
          tablas1 = tablas1.drop(columns=['(6)(7)','Unnamed: 1','Unnamed: 2','Unnamed: 4'])
          tablas1 = tablas1.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0':'Actividad','Unnamed: 3':'Capital Federal','Aires':'Gran Buenos Aires','Unnamed: 5':'Resto Bs As',
                                          'Unnamed: 6':'Catamarca','Unnamed: 7':'Cordoba','Unnamed: 8':'Corrientes','Unnamed: 9':'Chaco','Unnamed: 10':'Chubut',
                                          'Unnamed: 11':'Entre Rios','Unnamed: 12':'Formosa','Unnamed: 13':'Jujuy'})
          tablas1['ID'] = range(len(tablas1))
          return tablas1

      else:
        for tabla in tables:
          if len(tabla.columns) <= 17:
            tabla = tabla.drop(columns=['(6)(7)','Unnamed: 1'])
            tabla = tabla.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0':'Actividad','Unnamed: 2':'La Pampa','Unnamed: 3':'La Rioja','Unnamed: 4':'Mendoza',
                                            'Unnamed: 5':'Misiones','Unnamed: 6':'Neuquen','Unnamed: 7':'Rio Negro','Unnamed: 8':'Salta',
                                            'Unnamed: 9':'San Juan','Unnamed: 10':'San Luis','Unnamed: 11':'Santa Cruz','Unnamed: 12':'Santa Fe',
                                            'Estero':'Santiago del Estero','Fuego':'Tierra del Fuego','Unnamed: 13':'Tucuman'})
            tabla = pd.DataFrame(tabla)
            tablas2 = tablas2.append(tabla)

          elif len(tabla.columns) > 17:
            tabla = tabla.drop(columns=['(6)(7)','Unnamed: 1','Unnamed: 13'])
            tabla = tabla.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0':'Actividad','Unnamed: 2':'La Pampa','Unnamed: 3':'La Rioja','Unnamed: 4':'Mendoza',
                                          'Unnamed: 5':'Misiones','Unnamed: 6':'Neuquen','Unnamed: 7':'Rio Negro','Unnamed: 8':'Salta',
                                          'Unnamed: 9':'San Juan','Unnamed: 10':'San Luis','Unnamed: 11':'Santa Cruz','Unnamed: 12':'Santa Fe',
                                          'Estero':'Santiago del Estero','Fuego':'Tierra del Fuego','Unnamed: 14':'Tucuman'})
            tabla = pd.DataFrame(tabla)
            tablas2 = tablas2.append(tabla)
          
            tablas2 = tablas2.drop(columns=['Actividad'])
            tablas2['ID'] = range(len(tablas2))
            return tablas2
```

Then if I run a code like these it works nice:

```
enero2020 = provincias(202001, pages=[307,309]).merge(provincias(202001, pages=[308,310]), how='left', on='ID').drop(columns=['ID'])
febrero2020 = provincias(202002, pages=[307,309]).merge(provincias(202002, pages=[308,310]), how='left', on='ID').drop(columns=['ID'])
```

But I have troubles with June information. If I run this:

```
junio2021 = provincias(202106, pages=[313,315]).merge(provincias(202106, pages=[314,316]), how='left', on='ID').drop(columns=['ID'])
```

It gives me the error from the title: Can only merge Series or DataFrame objects, a <class 'NoneType'> was passed. I could see that the problem is on the merge part, but I've tried many things and couldn't solve it.

I saw that in the case of "junio2021" both pages [314,316] have the same column length, but I don't know if that could be the problem.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Seems like June 2021 data doesn't need that `if len(tabla.columns) <= 17:` because tabula gets all columns right this time.

In this case, creating an `'ID'` column is not neccessary because of `left_index=True, right_index=True` params in pandas merge.

Here it goes:

```
import pandas as pd
from tabula.io import read_pdf

def provincias(codigo,pages:list):
  box = [4,2.8,19,27]
  fc = 28.28
  for i in range(0, len(box)):
    box[i] *= fc

  path = "http://www.bcra.gob.ar/Pdfs/PublicacionesEstadisticas/BoletinEstadistico/" + 'boldat' + str(codigo) +".pdf"
  tables = read_pdf(path, pages=pages, area=[box], stream=True)

  df = pd.concat(tables).reset_index(drop=True)
  
  if pages[0] % 2 != 0:
    df = df.drop(columns=['(6)(7)','Unnamed: 1','Unnamed: 2','Unnamed: 4'])
    df = df.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0':'Actividad','Unnamed: 3':'Capital Federal','Aires':'Gran Buenos Aires','Unnamed: 5':'Resto Bs As',
                            'Unnamed: 6':'Catamarca','Unnamed: 7':'Cordoba','Unnamed: 8':'Corrientes','Unnamed: 9':'Chaco','Unnamed: 10':'Chubut',
                            'Unnamed: 11':'Entre Rios','Unnamed: 12':'Formosa','Unnamed: 13':'Jujuy'})
  else:
    df = df.drop(columns=['(6)(7)','Unnamed: 0','Unnamed: 1'])
    df = df.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 2':'La Pampa','Unnamed: 3':'La Rioja','Unnamed: 4':'Mendoza',
                            'Unnamed: 5':'Misiones','Unnamed: 6':'Neuquen','Unnamed: 7':'Rio Negro','Unnamed: 8':'Salta',
                            'Unnamed: 9':'San Juan','Unnamed: 10':'San Luis','Unnamed: 11':'Santa Cruz','Unnamed: 12':'Santa Fe',
                            'Estero':'Santiago del Estero','Fuego':'Tierra del Fuego','Unnamed: 13':'Tucuman'})
  return df
```

I tried for other months and tabula never gets it right so you need to use your previous code.

June 2021:

```
junio2021 = provincias(202106, pages=[313,315]).merge(provincias(202106, pages=[314,316]), left_index=True, right_index=True)
```